# Copy DLL From Assembly For Deployment

Tags: asp.net, deployment, assemblies, gac

NET on my local machine I have a reference to a DLL on my local assembly folder.  I was wondering how I can "package" this dll with the deployment of my website?  When I deploy on the staging server it starts complaining that it does not have that dll.  (It is not in the GAC of the staging server).  Thank you.

Comment: http://blog.kumarvineet.com/blog/post/2012/02/14/Copy-dll-from-GAC.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If your referenced DLL will not be in the GAC of the targeted computer then you should place the DLL in your web site's `\bin` folder.  For asp.net websites, referenced DLLs must exist in the GAC or in the `\bin` folder.  Alternatively, you could install your DLL into the GAC of your target computer using something like a WebSetup project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the DLL reference to CopyLocal = true?

Comment: Its not even in my DLL reference, its in my GAC.

Comment: if it's on GAC you need to have some reference in the web.config!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Save the Reference Location as relative paths so put in the a folder in your project and make sure the it proprieties "Copy Local" is true, it will make the VS to copy the file to the output directory.

Comment: How can I reference a dll thats in my assembly folder?  It's not letting me.

Comment: Why not? you add new reference -> Existing -> Goto the Assembly folder